# Why Expand and collapse is not working, After text search in Accordion List?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, accordion

I have implemented AccordionList by using these demo 1) https://github.com/kawanoshinobu/Ext.ux.AccordionList 2) http://docs.kawanoshinobu.com/accordionlist/ . Accordion list displayed very nicely. as per requirement need to live search text on accordion list. **I need to search text only in accordion list headers not in child nodes. After search, Once if got accordion headers should be able expand and collapse those headers.** I have tried by using this link http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/example/search-list. its working very nicely for list I have applied to AccordionList. It is searching from headers showing available headers, but i am not able to expand headers but it contains child nodes (saw child nodes by console.log(abc)). Clicking on expand and collapse, executing code proper without any error/issue. For more reference i have provided code in below. Can any body tell me how to achieve this one in accordion list? great appreciate. Thank you.

**Code is Here:**

```
 if(searchfield !== ""){
     store.filter([{
     property: "text",
     value: searchfield,
     anyMatch: true
     //exactMatch:true
    }]);
}
else{
    store.clearFilter();
}
```

**assigning this store value to accordion list code is below**

```
var accordionlistContent = {
                                xtype: 'accordionlist',
                                //store: Ext.create('eGMonitorApp.store.TestsStore'),
                                store: store,
                                name: 'accordionList',
                                height: 500,
                                headerItemTpl: [
                                    '<tpl if="this.isExpanded(values)">',
                                    '<div class="testsstatus{status}"></div></div>',
                                    '<div style="width:80%;margin-left: 10px" <tpl if="values.year">style="font-style:italic; "</tpl>>',
                                    '{text}</div>',
                                    '<div class="down"></div>',
                                    '<tpl else>',
                                    '<div class="testsstatus{status}"></div></div>',
                                    '<div style="width:80%;margin-left: 10px"<tpl if="values.year">style="font-style:italic;"</tpl>>',
                                    '{text}</div>',
                                    '<div class="right"></div>',
                                    '</tpl>'
                                ].join(''),
                                contentItemTpl: [
                                    '<div class="testsstatus{status}"></div></div>',
                                    '<div style="margin-left: 10px" >{text}<div>'
                                ].join(''),
                                useSelectedHighlights: false,
                                indent: true
                            }
```

**Expand/Collapse code:**

```
doAllExpand: function() {       
        var me = this;
        me.doAll(function expand(node) {
            if (me.getAnimation()) {
                me.addListExpandListeners(node);
            }
            node.expand();
            if (!node.isLeaf()) {
                node.childNodes.forEach(expand, me);
            }
        });
    },

doAllCollapse: function() {

        var me = this;
        me.doAll(function collapse(node) {
            node.collapse();
            if (!node.isLeaf()) {
                node.childNodes.forEach(collapse, me);
            }
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achived. store.filter function, filter the text nicely but if it has child nodes also it wont show. because we have searched some particular text on store. after filter shows only those filter text. I have gone another way. it is working very nicely as per my requirement. I am calling web service store.load(). **In store searching for entered text. if entered text is not available at parent level, removing that particular items form store. After iteration, final store assigning to accordion list.** accordion list shows related search text data. cheers :). below is code. Thank you.

```
store.getProxy().setUrl('resources/Json/TestsStore.json');           
            store.load({
                scope: this,
                callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                    if (success) {
                            if(searchfield !=="") {                                
                                if(store.data.items.length !==0){
                                    var length = store.data.items.length;
                                    for(var j=length; j--;) {
                                    if(store.data.items[j].data.name.search(new RegExp(searchfield, "i")) ===-1){
                                        store.data.items[j].remove();
                                    }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                        if(store.data.items.length ===0){
                            eGMonitorApp.util.Utility.showAlert('Searched text not available.','Tests');
                        }                       
                        this.getAccordionListRef().setStore(store);
                    }
                }
            });
```